# How do I invoke changes to a custom view object from its activity

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity

I have a custom view that draws to a canvas.  I am trying to invoke changes to the canvas when the user pushes a button from the activity that this view is tied to.  Currently, I am attempting to do this by calling a public method, called setNewDrawable, that I created inside the view.

The debugger is giving me different values for the view ID depending on whether I'm inside setNewDrawable or inside the Overridden onDraw method when I post an Invalidate.

For example the debugger variables show: (This - MyView id=830067720176) or (This - MyView id=830067712344) in setNewDrawable and onDraw respectively.  This makes me think I basically have two copies of the object and I am essentially interacting with the wrong one.

How can I get information to my custom View in order to determine what it draws?

Here is the code I am running.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    MyView mView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);   
        mView= (MyView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_view);

        //A button to modify what's drawn on the canvas
        Button switchLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switch_left);
        switchLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mView.setNewDrawable();
                mView.postInvalidate();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the layout inflater.  I removed it and it worked fine.